# Getting NSView to appear programmatically in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsview

I have a NSView object that is being returned to me as a result of a function.  I know the view is valid because I can see the contents of the view if I do this:

```
NSRect rect = NSMakeRect(600,600,200,200);
                    NSWindow *testWindow = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:rect styleMask:NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask backing: NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
                    [[testWindow contentView] addSubview:returnedView];
                    [testWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:NSApp];
```

In my application I have a window with a custom view (has some text on it) that has an outlet referenced in my code using IBOutlet.  I'm trying to add the view I'm getting returned as a subview of that outlet.

```
[referencedView addSubView:returnedView]
[referencedView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

The referenced view is visible (I can see the text in it), but the returnedView doesn't appear on top.  Am I forgetting something?

This is what my code looks like now:

```
[returnedView setFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,200,200)];
                    [referencedView addSubview:returnedView];
                    [referencedView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
                    [referencedView drawRect:[referencedView bounds]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Views can only be in ONE superview is what I just learned.  I had the test code and the code I wanted to work so it was removing my view and putting it in the window instead.

Answer (score 0):

That custom view (with the text in it) has a custom `drawRect` implementation, in which the text is drawn, right? In this case, my idea is that you'd want to call `super`'s implementation of `drawRect` to make sure that the subviews get drawn too.

Comment: The custom view (with the text in it) is in a nib file.  Do I have to do something special to the view in the nib file to make it support adding subViews? (I wouldn't think so, but I'm new to cocoa)